# Splitting a list of strings separating the non-numeric and numeric parts

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a nested list consisting of strings. Each string has a non-numeric part and a part with a string representation of numbers.

```
lis = {{"a (b) 1","c 2"},{"d 3","e f 4"}}
```

I need to split these string elements so that the string representation of numbers are separated as follow:

```
res = {{{"a (b)","1"},{"c","2"}},{{"d","3"},{"e f","4"}}}
```

I am not sure how to come up with the necessary pattern for `StringSplit`.  Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
StringSplit[#, WhitespaceCharacter... ~~ n : NumberString :> n] & /@ lis
```

> {{{"a (b)", "1"}, {"c", "2"}}, {{"d", "3"}, {"e f", "4"}}}

Comment: that was fast! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an equivalent to kglr's solution, using replacement and regex:

```
{{"a (b) 1", "c 2"}, {"d 3", "e f 4"}} /. 
s_String :> StringCases[s, RegularExpression["(.+) (\\d)$"] :> Sequence["$1", "$2"]]
   {{{"a (b)", "1"}, {"c", "2"}}, {{"d", "3"}, {"e f", "4"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a copy of J.M.'s answer using `StringExpression`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lis = {{"a (b) 1", "c 2"}, {"d 3", "e f 4"}};

sc = StringCases[#, 
    StartOfString ~~ b : Shortest[___] ~~ k : NumberString :> 
     Sequence @@ {StringTrim@b, k}] &;

Map[sc, lis]
```

{{{"a (b)", "1"}, {"c", "2"}}, {{"d", "3"}, {"e f", "4"}}}